# Tick escaped hyphen in column name begets "unknown column in 'field list'"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    // get media table columns 
    $media_columns = $this->many( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM media;" ); 
    $media_fields = array(); // array to filter out unnecessary col data  
    $pk_name = 'ignore_this'; 
    foreach( $media_columns as $col ) { 
        $field = $col['Field']; 
        if( $field !== $pk_name ) { 
            array_push($media_fields, '`'.$field.'`'); 
        } 
    } 
    $fields_str = "(".implode(",", $media_fields).")"; // put in string 
    // we will be overriding the campaign_uid with parent_uid 
    $insert_str = str_replace("`campaign_uid`", "'$parent_uid'", implode(',', $media_fields) ); 

    // duplicate draft media, pointing to parent campaign 
    $this->none( 
        "INSERT INTO media ". 
        "$fields_str ". 
        "SELECT $insert_str ". 
        "FROM media WHERE `campaign_uid`='$campaign_uid' " 
    );
```

Which throws an error:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'ADO Error: Unknown column 'margin-left' in 'field list' { INSERT INTO media (`ignore_this`,`nonprofit_uid`,`campaign_uid`,`meta_id`,`image_name`,`url`,`type`,`subtype`,`mark`,`last_updated`,`deleted`,`margin-left`,`margin-top`) 
SELECT `ignore_this`,`nonprofit_uid`,'XXXXXX',`meta_id`,`image_name`,`url`,`type`,`subtype`,`mark`,`last_updated`,`deleted`,`margin-left`,`margin-top` FROM media 
WHERE `campaign_uid`='XXXXXXXXXXX }'
```

Before you ask about the funky sql wrapper functions: don't.  I've inherited a mess of a codebase from my predecessor, and am largely locked into using his functions.

For the same reason, we have hyphens in the mysql column names.  Because it's `margin-left` that fails, I suspect that this is the problem, but there's enough hard-coded references to that column name all over the place the refactoring isn't a very attractive option.

The funny part is, I'm pulling the field names directly from a SHOW COLUMNS call, and escaping them with ticks.  I don't understand how the column can't be found if it was just read from the DB a second ago.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `show columns`. That was never really intended for how you're using it. Use the `information_schema` meta-db instead:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where (TABLE_SCHEMA='name of db') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'name of your table')
```

Comment: Thanks!  is there any way to keep it db_name agnostic, so that I can point it at a testing db?

Comment: just make the table_schema be a variable you reset elsewhere. name it one thing for devel, another for production.

Comment: I appreciate snippets like this that do it "the right way", but after implementing it, this did not solve my problem (nor could it, really, as it produces the same faulty query string)

Comment: I'd check in to where exactly this `margin-left` and whatnot business is coming from. `-` isn't a valid field name character in mysql to begin with.